# How much electric energy is created by an 80kg man making a step at flat surface while walking at the normal speed (5km/h)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, electricity, newtonian-gravity, potential

Even a rough approximation would be helpful.  But of course a precise calculation would be great :).  Thank you all in advance very much for your help!

By the way - do you have any suggestion for physicists freelance platform?

Comment: Homework-like questions should ask about a specific physics concept and show some effort to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users.

Comment: You should say how much work is done instead of how much energy is created

Comment: This is not a homework - although I guess it easily could be. I want to calculate how much energy could be harvested from walking.  When 80kg person hits the road with his heel and that energy could be converted to electricity - how much would it be?

Comment: And let me explain the use for the broader community and future users (BTW amazing, how easy it is to judge others): Just for the sake of calculation (let's say it's 2Wh but we will be able to harvest only 50% - 1Wh). Let's say in 10 years everyone will be harvesting this energy - let's say people make on average 5000 steps per day, 7 billion people on earth will produce 35,000 TWh per day. But my intuition says it is probably less.

Comment: I would put the bit about you wanting to know how much **electrical** energy is produced in your post and title, comments get deleted and I don't think you specify electrical energy, just energy.

Comment: - thanks for suggestion, I just did make the edits.

Comment: The homework policy applies to all homework-like exercises. The distinction between what is set as homework and what is personal curiosity is irrelevant to the policy. ... What do you mean by "physists freelance platform"? If you are asking for recommended sites with **might** accept questions like this, see http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/.